# What would be a proper name for the concept of setting up and tearing down a unit-test context?

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing, interface, naming

Basically all unit-testing frameworks I've used, be it in C++ or C# (or anything else, I guess), have had the concept of **setup** and **teardown** to establish reusable contexts for many test cases.

Right now I'm doing some related work (**EDIT: this work has nothing to do with testing, but the setup/teardown concept is the same**) where I want to abstract this concept so that a setup/teardown pair can be associated with a task of some kind by using an interface with setup() and teardown().

However, I have a hard time naming this interface. Right now it's (pseudocode)

```
interface IConfigurator
{
    void Setup();
    void Teardown();
}
```

but I don't like that name. What would be a better and more descriptive name for this setup/teardown concept?

Comment: I don't know of an official term and I'm the worst when it comes to names. In fact, I made an `IConfigurator` interface myself recently ... I used `Register`/`Unregister` but the purpose was significantly different from yours.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. See my **EDIT** - the work I'm doing now has nothing to do with testing, but the setup/teardown concept is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **context** instead of **configurator**. It better describes the concept.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
interface ILifetime
{
    void Start();
    void End();
}
```

Comment: Nice, or how about IExistence - Start(); End();

Answer (score 1):

1. Beware, not all testing frameworks have the concept of setup/teardown (e.g., xUnit). Why can't you just use the constructor and `IDisposable`?
2. Why would you want to abstract this concept? What purpose is it serving?
3. If you really do want to abstract this concept, I think it should be

   `IBeforeAnyTests {
       void Setup();
   }`

   `IAfterAllTests {
        void Teardown();
    }`

Because the two concepts are separate responsibilities!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. See my **EDIT** - the work I'm doing now has nothing to do with testing, but the setup/teardown concept is there. Why I would want it? In much the same way that deterministic destruction is wanted in C++. I want to ensure that a defined set of operations are performed both before executing a task and after.

Comment: @Johann Gerell: My answer stands. These are distinct responsibilities and they should be in separate interfaces. I don't see why you can't just use the constructor/`IDisposable`, but barring that, if it's not for testing, what is wrong with `ISetup` and `ITeardown`?

Comment: Thanks for making me rethink my position once more. The outcome is the same though. I see it as one concept with one responsibility: to ensure that the playground looks the same after a task as it did before. We can argue to hell and back about this, but the simple fact is that our opinions differ. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about IControlledContext ? (some would argue that the I is redundant).

Comment: I wouldn't argue that it's redundant in C#, since it's the official naming guide and a defacto standard there. Breaking it would bring more badness by confusion than UncleBob goodness.

Comment: @Johann: I hear you and admire your courage to defy the will of the almighty Uncle in the sky :o)

Comment: As much as I love most of his higher level thoughts, SOLID as  the prime example, I disagree with many of the details he narrow-mindedly fiddles around with, for example that IOC containers are pointless.

Comment: @Johann: I aggree. His book "Clean Code" was an eyeopener to me... a real classic that i promote eagerly. Still, there are things that I choose not to follow.